# Don't create table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a huge SQL file, and I want it to not insert a specific table.

The code is

```
CREATE TABLEW IF NOT EXISTS 'table_name'
```

Is there some way to ignore it all somehow? I don't want this table to be created, but I can't remove about a million lines manually.

Comment: Though not always the best option, you can use find and replace tools such as [`sed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) to remove/edit the (un)desired create table statements without manually opening the whole file at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the table before executing the script.  If it has `create table blah if not exists ...` then if the table already exists, it will skip that statement.

Comment: Is there a program that can import a SQL file, then it reads which tables are supposed to be created, and I can untick them?

Comment: I figured it out. Not by your solution, but I'm grateful for trying to help me. I'll mark it